# Insert truncate query result into a table

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a query reside in a access file(.mdb), I would like to call this query in VBA, and store the result into a existing table. The previous content of the table should be deleted before the result was inserted.

Any idea? In my existing code, the query name "genInboundCdr" was execute via DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet and result was stored into a excel file.

---

```
Private Sub BtnExecuteQuery_Click()
    If IsNull(txtOutputPath.value) Then
        MsgBox "Please enter a valid output file location."
    Else
        If ObjectExists("Query", "genInboundCdr") Then
            strPathToSave = txtOutputPath.value
            MsgBox "About to extract inbound cdr..." & vbCrLf & _
                    "Please notice that the query may take longer time " & _
                    "( > 20 minutes ) if the linked tables contains a lot " & _
                    "of records."
            txtStatus.value = txtStatus.value & _
                    "About to extract inbound cdr..." & vbCrLf & _
                    "Please notice that the query may take longer time " & _
                    "( > 20 minutes ) if the linked tables contains a lot " & _
                    "of records." & vbCrLf
            DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, _
                                        acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
                                        "genInboundCdr", _
                                        strPathToSave, _
                                        True
            MsgBox ("Inbound Cdr generated.")
            txtStatus.value = txtStatus.value & "Inbound Cdr generated." & vbCrLf
        Else
            MsgBox ("Query does not exist! Please review your steps.")
        End If

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: No. It is execute in a access form. You misunderstand it. It only generate the result into a excel file. That doesn't matter. Now I don't want to store the result in excel file, but a table in the access file.

Comment: Why did you delete your comment? It makes me look like I am talking to myself.

Comment: because it weas no longer relevant. People here are smart ennough to understand!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I end up doing like this:
1) query and store the result into a excel file.
2) import the excel file using transferspreadsheet.

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, _
                            acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
                            "genInboundCdr", _
                            strPathToSave, _
                            True
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, _
                            acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
                            "temp_result", _
                            strPathToSave, _
                            True
```

Comment: All I've done here is insert the line continuation character (_) so that it formats nicer.

Comment: This is really a substandard solution to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing to do is execute a delete query on the destination table and then use an append query.

A delete query's SQL looks like this:

```
DELETE *
FROM foo2;
```

An append query's SQL likes like this:

```
INSERT INTO foo_dest ( f0, f1, f2, f3 )
SELECT foo_src.f0, foo_src.f1, foo_src.f2, foo_src.f3
FROM foo_src;
```

The SELECT portion would be your source query (genInboundCdr).

You can execute either one of these query in VBA like this:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL = "insert into ..."
```

or

```
Currentdb.execute = "insert into ..."
```

or if you prefer to use stored queries

```
DoCmd.OpenQuery "genInboundCdr"
```

(there may be another way to run genInboundCdr, but I can't recall right now)